# Why is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}(T=k)]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \mathbb{P}[T=k]$

Tags: probability, summation, expectation

Let $T$ be a non-negative random variable.

Why is it true that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}(T=k)]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \mathbb{P}[T=k]$$

According to me it would make sense that $\mathbb{E}[1(T=k)]=\mathbb{P}[T=k]$.

So where is my mistake or is the statement above false?

**More Context:**

When $X_i$ are i.i.d. random variables, independent of $T$ with $\mathbb{E}[T_i]=\mu$, $Y_i:=|X_i|$, then we have for $S_k:=\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$ that

$$\mathbb{E}[|S_{T}|]\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[Y_k]\mathbb{E}[1(T=k)]=\mathbb{E}[Y_1]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \mathbb{P}[T=k]=\mathbb{E}[Y_1]\mathbb{E}[T].$$

Maybe I misinterpret it and the question I ask about is wrong, or the master solution is wrong.

Comment: Maybe $\sum_{k=0}^\infty kP\{T=k\}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P\{T\ge k\}$ when $T$ is discrete?

Comment: I mean that your equality is false...

Comment: user should reveal the secret source of this misinformation!

Comment: It could be that it is false. It is found in our proof (if I do not misinterpret it) of Wald's equations, proving that $S_T$ is integrable for $S_T=\sum_{k=1}^T X_k$, where $X_k$ are independent random variables. But maybe I misinterpret something, here would be the link to it:
http://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2015/math/asp/ASP_2015_Exercise03
Exercise 3.1, solution:
http://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2015/math/asp/ASP_2015_Solution01

Comment: @user136457 There is an inequality in the first line (solution of 3.1(a))...

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks for the link, but that it actually not what I am looking for. This is the proof for Wald's Equation with $\tau$ a stopping time. In this exercise we try to prove some similar result without assuming that $T$ is a stopping time. Or do you think it would work the same way then?

Comment: @d.k.o yes, there is an inequality, due to something similar as the triangle inequality, I suppose. But after this inequality we still have the equality I stated above, don't we?

Comment: Oh. I see. This is because $\mathbb{E}Y_k=k\cdot \mathbb{E}Y_1$

Comment: @d.k.o maybe I make a huge mistake, but isn't this inequality you state in the wrong direction in order to help me prove the whole statement made in the solution of 3.1 (a)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually I worked with the wrong definition of $Y_k$ (and also posted the wrong definition of it in the question). 
This absolutely makes sense to me now! Thanks a lot! And sorry for the stupid question and not paying more attention at the definitions.

Comment: maybe an "off-topic" question here: Should I delete this question now?